# Debugging PHP during a jQuery.getJSON request

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to debug some PHP that is called from a jQuery.getJSON request. Everything works on my local machine and one other server but I am having trouble getting it to work on my new server.

I have boiled it down to the following lines:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');

$url = 'http://findyourmp.parliament.uk/api/search?q='.$_GET['q'].'&f=json';
$feed = file_get_contents($url);
```

Is there anyway I can see which one of these is failing? How would I output these variables without the PHP files sending a response back to the initial jQuery call?

It's all a bit confusing as it works fine on my local machine and other server..

Thanks

Comment: Yes, look in the error logs for the server.

Comment: chances are this line is failing require_once('../../../../wp-load.php'); as this is using relative paths , so check the correc t paths and see if they match this line

Comment: You can write to a log file and check it

Comment: just try to check under the hood, enable error reporting and check the browser console on the network tab

Comment: you can check the error log file in server or try to run the code $url = 'http://findyourmp.parliament.uk/api/search?q='.$_GET['q'].'&f=json';
$feed = file_get_contents($url); in a separate php file. Instead of $_GET['q'], give some text check whether $feed is getting any output so you are able to know that first two lines giving error if these lines run

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting AJAX PHP scripts can sometimes be a hassle! The easiest way would be to see what the console is showing as **RESPONSE HEADERS** in the **XHR** section. That doesn't always apply, however.

One thing I've been doing is writing a small script that I can use independently of the rest of the application. Something like this:

```
<?
require( ................. ); // make sure you include all files you need for the ajax script
error_reporting(ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
include('my.ajax.script.php'); // the AJAX script in question goes here
?>
```

Save that on your server as `ajxchecker.php` and you can call it anytime for a quick response.

Answer (score -1):

Use FireFox. Install the FireBug extension and then install FirePHP.

```
http://getfirebug.com/
http://www.firephp.org/
```

You will then be able to fully debug your php code.

Comment: Curious as to why I was downvoted. The OP asked how he could view variables and debug his code. Firebug and Firephp provides that capability.